# Python Validictory- Field Validation

Tags: python

How to identify in python , where the validation failed using python's "validictory" package,?
`"Failed to validate field '_data' list schema"`- Is there a way to find out which field validation failed?

Comment: You should accept and answer by clicking tick mark beside the answer if you find any helpful .I see you did not accept any answer any of your question.If you don't accept answer people  may lose interest to answer your questions.please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
import validictory
schema = {"type":"object","properties":{"field1": {"type":"string", "minLength":3},"field2":{"type":"integer"}}}
try:
    validictory.validate({'field1':"ab",'field2':123},schema)
except validictory.FieldValidationError as e:
    print "field which failed validation:",e.fieldname
```

**field which failed validation: field1**

```
try:  
    validictory.validate({'field1':"abcd",'field2':123.7},schema)  
except validictory.FieldValidationError as e:  
    print "field which failed validation:",e.fieldname
```

**field which failed validation: field2**

Answer (score 0):

Using type as the object in validictory, and mentioning the key (as the field name) for the properties dictionary, the field which failed validation can be identified